# How to use only COUNT(*) in my query to find days with only red boats?

Tags: sql

Given the following database below, I am trying to figure a way where I can list the days from the reservation table that have ONLY red boats reserved using only the COUNT(*) function. From looking at the tables, only Monday and Sunday should be displayed since only red boats are reserved on those days. Wednesday should not be included because there is a blue boat reserved on that day as well. I am not exactly sure how to even go about doing this using only COUNT(*).

(sailor)
sname   rating
Brutus  1
Andy    8
Horatio 7
Rusty   8
Bob     1

(reservation)
sname   bname   day

Andy  Interlake Monday
Andy  Bay       Wednesday
Andy  Marine    Saturday
Rusty Bay       Sunday
Rusty Interlake Wednesday
Rusty Marine    Wednesday
Bob   Bay       Monday

(boat)
bname      color  rating
SpeedQueen white  9
Interlake  red    8
Marine     blue   7
Bay        red    3

(alldays)
day
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday

So far I have managed to come up with the following, although it should only display Monday and Sunday.

```
select distinct day
from reservation
where (
select count(*)
from reservation r, boat b
where r.day=reservation.day and
      r.bname=b.bname and
      r.color = 'red')
```

The following is what is displayed:
Monday
Wednesday
Sunday

Edit: sorry about the spacing in the tables. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Create table  and  inserts statements to describe your tables. Also, you don't need the count function. (Take that back, ONLY requires count)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "only using the count() function".  Your example uses distinct, joins, where clauses, and a sub table; if I can use all of those myself, I can give you an answer that doesn't even require count(*)

Comment: I highly recommend avoiding implicit joins and explicitly naming the join type (`INNER JOIN` in this case) with an `ON` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT rcount.day
(
    SELECT day, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM reservations
    GROUP BY day
) rcount
JOIN
(
    SELECT day, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM reservations res JOIN boats b ON res.bname = b.bname
    WHERE b.color = 'red'
    GROUP BY day
) red_res_count
ON rcount.day = red_res_count.day
WHERE red_res_count.cnt = rcount.cnt
```

This gets the total number of reservations by day, and joins them with the number of red reservations per day. If the number of red reservations = total reservations for the day, you know there are only red reservations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select r.day
from reservations r join
     boats b
     on r.bname = b.bname
group by r.day
having count(*) = count(case when b.color = 'red' then b.bname end);
```